# Responsive center alignment of DIV but not text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, footer

I want to center a DIV within a DIV but not the text, all the solutions are saying to specify my width and set margins to auto, but how does that work if it's a responsive build as if I set the width it wont be? I want to align the contact-info DIVS but not the text. Hope that is clear enough.

Thanks!

```html
<div id="upperfooter">
  <div class="container">
   <div id="links">
 <div class="contact-info col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-3 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">
    <div class="contact-item">
      <h3><strong>COMPANY INFO</strong></h3>
      <p>About Nielsen</p>
     <p>Investor Relations</p>
     <p>Nielsen Families</p>
     <p>Responsibility & Sustainability</p>
     <p>Press Room</p>
     <p>Careers</p>
     <p>Contact Us</p>
    </div>
 </div>
   <div class="contact-info col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-3 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">
    <div class="contact-item">
      <h3><strong>INSIGHTS</strong></h3>
      <p>Newswire</p>
      <p>Reports</p>
      <p>News Center</p>
      <p>Top 10 &amp; Trends</p>
      <p>How We Measure</p>
      <p>Webinars &amp; Events</p>
      <p>Newsletter Sign-up</p>
    </div>
 </div>
    <div class="contact-info col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-3 col-xs-4 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">
    <div class="contact-item">
      <h3><strong>SOLUTIONS</strong></h3>
      <p>Advertising Effectiveness</p>
      <p>Audience Measurement</p>
      <p>Marketing ROI</p>
      <p>Price and Promotion</p>
      <p>Product Development</p>
      <p>Reputation Management</p>
      <p>Shopper</p>
    </div>
 </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What divs you want to center, right now, all the divs with class **contact-item** are centered inside divs with class **contact-info**. You want to center the **col-lg-3** on the div with id **links** when the screen size is large? Please, can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `position: relative` to main div and set the smaller width on a contact div, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only elements I see not centered are those with **contact-info**, but only when screen size is large, an approach is to add some style to the wrapper. Also, you have to remenber that **col-x** divs should by wrapped by a div with **row class** on Bootstrap. So, we going to add style `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` to this wrapper. Check next example, where redundant classes where removed and borders where added so you have a reference on the visualization.

```css
.contact-info {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.contact-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="upperfooter">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="links" class="row">

      <div class="contact-info col-lg-3 col-xs-4">
        <div class="contact-item">
          <h3><strong>COMPANY INFO</strong></h3>
          <p>About Nielsen</p>
          <p>Investor Relations</p>
          <p>Nielsen Families</p>
          <p>Responsibility & Sustainability</p>
          <p>Press Room</p>
          <p>Careers</p>
          <p>Contact Us</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-info col-lg-3 col-xs-4">
        <div class="contact-item">
          <h3><strong>INSIGHTS</strong></h3>
          <p>Newswire</p>
          <p>Reports</p>
          <p>News Center</p>
          <p>Top 10 &amp; Trends</p>
          <p>How We Measure</p>
          <p>Webinars &amp; Events</p>
          <p>Newsletter Sign-up</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-info col-lg-3 col-xs-4">
        <div class="contact-item">
          <h3><strong>SOLUTIONS</strong></h3>
          <p>Advertising Effectiveness</p>
          <p>Audience Measurement</p>
          <p>Marketing ROI</p>
          <p>Price and Promotion</p>
          <p>Product Development</p>
          <p>Reputation Management</p>
          <p>Shopper</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @OllieRichardson Nice, just letme know if you need more feedback, or my approach don't fit your goals.